# SQL Query Order of Operations

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing

It Friday. My brain is fried. This is very simple and I'm ashamed for asking this:

I simply want to query against my Event table (which has a non-null Start Time and nullable End time).However, given my unit test, I keep getting 2 records back (the 2:00 and the 4:00 records, not just the 2:00 as I'd expect)

```
SELECT 
    EventId, 
    TaskId, 
    MachineId, 
    LoginId, 
    EventStartTimeUtc, 
    EventEndTimeUtc, 
    OpCode, 
    UnitId, 
    PositionId, 
    WebId, 
    Comment, 
    MakereadyCount, 
    GrossCount, 
    NetCount, 
    PerpetualGross, 
    PerpetualNet, 
    PerpetualMakeready, 
    TaskState, 
    EventTypeId, 
    IsAutoEvent, 
    IsTransferred, 
    LastUpdatedTimeUtc
FROM Event
WHERE MachineId = #MachineId# 
    AND EventStartTimeUtc >= #StartTimeUtc# 
    AND (EventEndTimeUtc IS NULL 
        OR ((EventEndTimeUtc IS NOT NULL) AND EventEndTimeUtc <![CDATA[<=]]> #EndTimeUtc#))
[Test]
public void ShouldSelectEventsInRange()
{
    //Arrange
    TaskDto testTask = _testRepository.CreateTask(new TaskDto { TaskId = 1234567 }, true);

    var machineId = ((ArtemisRepository)_testRepository).CreateMachine(123, "MR40SIM", "0V7", 200, 100, 555555); //Requires a 555555 down-task to exist in database

    EventRecordDto result = _testRepository.CreateEvent(new EventRecordDto {TaskId = testTask.TaskId, MachineId = machineId, EventStartTimeUtc = new DateTime(2014, 4, 15, 1, 50, 0), OpCode = "100", MakereadyCount = 1752, GrossCount = 5660, NetCount = 2512, Comment = "Test Event", IsAutoEvent = false, IsTransferred = false});
    EventRecordDto result2 = _testRepository.CreateEvent(new EventRecordDto {TaskId = testTask.TaskId, MachineId = machineId, EventStartTimeUtc = new DateTime(2014, 4, 15, 2, 0, 0), OpCode = "100", MakereadyCount = 1752, GrossCount = 5660, NetCount = 2512, Comment = "Test Event", IsAutoEvent = false, IsTransferred = false});
    EventRecordDto result3 = _testRepository.CreateEvent(new EventRecordDto {TaskId = testTask.TaskId, MachineId = machineId, EventStartTimeUtc = new DateTime(2014, 4, 15, 4, 0, 0), OpCode = "100", MakereadyCount = 1752, GrossCount = 5660, NetCount = 2512, Comment = "Test Event", IsAutoEvent = false, IsTransferred = false});

    //Act
    var results = _testRepository.SelectEventsInRange(machineId, new DateTime(2014, 4, 15, 2, 0, 0), new DateTime(2014, 4, 15, 3, 59, 59));

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(results.Count == 1, "{0} records came, instead of the 1 record expeted!", new object[] { results.Count });
    Assert.IsTrue(results.Any(r => r.EventId == result2.EventId), "Expected Event (Id: {0}), Actual Event (ID: {1})", new object[] { result2.EventId, results[0].EventId});
}
```

Comment: why don't you mock your database calls?

Comment: The is more an integration test since iBATIS is such a configuration-heavy data access layer. I have separate unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query asks for records where the `EventStartTimeUtc` is greater than or equal to 2:00, which both those records are, and where the `EventEndTimeUtc` is null, which they both are.

Did you mean `EventStartTimeUtc` where you have `EventEndTimeUtc` in the WHERE clause?

Comment: SO obvious. Thank you for the sanity check ;)

I'll create separate test for the NULL checks and use this for when records aren't null.